# How to maintain state of checkboxes of Datatable when data loaded via ajax.

Tags: ajax, datatables

I am trying to load Datatable rows with server side calling. I have around 30000 data. By default I have loaded 200 data per page with pagination. Each row contains checkbox. Now the problem is that, suppose I have checked 5 checkboxes among 200 datas, next when going next page and back to previous page again the 5 checkboxes showed me unchecked. How I can now maintain the state of the checkboxes even if I travel through pages. Please help me to give a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Long answer short: Save the state of the CheckBoxes and recover it when needed. :)

Comment: Is the checkbox directly related to/part of the data or are they external? In other words, does each row have a (example) isActive column with a value of 1/0, t/f, or are these checkboxes used to select rows for manipulation in DataTables?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) extension that provides universal solution for working with checkboxes in a table in both client-side and server-side processing modes.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'processing': true,
   'serverSide': true,
   'ajax': '/your/script',
   'columnDefs': [
      {
        'targets': 0,
        'checkboxes': true
      }
   ],
   'order': [[1, 'asc']]
});
```